# Create a table with counts and percentages with missing data

Tags: r, datatable, count, percentage, kableextra

I am trying to create a table with preset dimensions and have R fill in the counts and percentages. This is for an R-markdown report.

Here is the code for my sample data.

```
#This is the most realistic data I could produce.
Maj <- rep("Major A", times=50)
set.seed(24601) 
Race <- sample(c("Asian","Black", "Am Indian","Hawiian" ,"Hispanic","White","Two or More Races","Not Reported"),
                 prob=c(.01,.1,.01,.01,.02,.80,.05,.01),size=50, replace = T)
Sex <- sample(c("Female","Male"), prob=c(.98,.02),size=50,replace=T)

Enroll_MajorA <- cbind(Maj,Sex,Race)
```

I need the table to calculate a count and a percent whether or not a given Race and Sex combination exists in the data set. Here is what I need it to look like.

[image: Table Format]

I have tried computing each value for the table individually and R-markdown gave me a "memory error". I have tried creating a count and percent table and combining them together but it does not give all of the Race/Sex combinations I need for the report. I am not sure where to go from here. Please Help!

Comment: are your data put into factors?

Comment: No, they are not as factors

Comment: they need to be factors if you want to get all levels / combinations of levels with `table`

Comment: What does percentage refer to? Percentage of all females that are from some race, or share of females in a particular race?

Comment: Percentage of each sex/race combination.

Comment: @Cath sometimes there would be any of a race or gender. Making factors would include the ones not present in the data. I still need to include them. For example, using there not any people listed as Asian, I still need to list as zero and a zero percent.

Comment: `Enroll_MajorA <- data.frame(Maj, Sex=factor(Sex, levels=c("Female", "Male")), Race=factor(Race, levels=c("Asian","Black", "Am Indian","Hawiian" ,"Hispanic","White","Two or More Races","Not Reported"))); with(Enroll_MajorA, table(Sex, Race))`

Comment: @asokol no problem ;-)

Comment: @Cath does the semicolon indicate a newline?

Comment: the semicolon is to separate the 2 statements but yes,you can replace it with a newline

Comment: linked post and possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5558745/4137985

Comment: @Cath How would you include the percentages?

Comment: with `prop.table`: `prop.table(table(...))`

Comment: @Cath How would you combine the count table ```tab1<- with(Enroll_MajorA, table(Sex, Race))``` and the percent table ```pct1<-with(Enroll_MajorA, prop.table(tab1))``` into one table as shown in the pictue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `aggregate`. You can keep the matrix untouched, since you can use `as.data.frame`, which coerces automatically into countable factors. The `NROW` (capitals) doesn't discriminate between matrices and vectors.

```
m.agg <- do.call(data.frame, 
                 aggregate(. ~ Sex + Race, as.data.frame(Enroll_MajorA), function(x) 
                   c(count=as.integer(NROW(x)), share=NROW(x) / NROW(Enroll_MajorA))))
```

To get the complete set, we may merge with an `expand.grid`, which we may want to clean up a little.

```
res <- merge(as.data.frame(m.agg), expand.grid(Sex=c("Female", "Male"), 
                                               Race=relevant.races), all=TRUE)  # `relevant.races` below
res[, 3:4][is.na(res[, 3:4])] <- 0  # transform `NA` into 0 to be nice
res[order(res[, "Race"]), ]  # order output
#       Sex              Race Maj.count Maj.share
# 1  Female             Black         2      0.04
# 10   Male             Black         0      0.00
# 2  Female           Hawiian         1      0.02
# 3  Female          Hispanic         1      0.02
# 11   Male          Hispanic         0      0.00
# 4  Female Two or More Races         2      0.04
# 12   Male Two or More Races         0      0.00
# 5  Female             White        44      0.88
# 13   Male             White         0      0.00
# 6  Female             Asian         0      0.00
# 14   Male             Asian         0      0.00
# 7  Female        Am. Indian         0      0.00
# 15   Male        Am. Indian         0      0.00
# 8  Female          Hawaiian         0      0.00
# 16   Male          Hawaiian         0      0.00
# 9  Female      Not Reported         0      0.00
# 17   Male      Not Reported         0      0.00
```

#### Data

```
relevant.races <- c("Asian","Black", "Am. Indian", "Hawaiian" , "Hispanic", "White", 
                    "Two or More Races", "Not Reported")

Enroll_MajorA <- structure(c("Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", 
"Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", 
"Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", 
"Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", 
"Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", 
"Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", 
"Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", 
"Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Major A", 
"Major A", "Major A", "Major A", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "White", "White", 
"White", "Hawiian", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", 
"White", "White", "White", "White", "Two or More Races", "White", 
"White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "Hispanic", 
"White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "Two or More Races", 
"White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", 
"White", "Black", "White", "White", "Black", "White", "White", 
"White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White"
), .Dim = c(50L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Maj", "Sex", 
"Race")))
```

Comment: @Cath should fit perfectly now :)

Comment: @Cath I almost had a suspicion.^^

Answer (score 0):

One way using `tidyverse` using `.drop = FALSE` which will include missing factor levels

```
library(tidyverse)

Enroll_MajorA %>%
   group_by(Race, Sex, .drop = FALSE) %>%
   summarise(count = n()) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   mutate(perc = count/sum(count)) %>%
   gather(key, value, -Sex, -Race) %>%
   unite(Race, Race, key) %>%
   spread(Race, value)
```

**data**

As commented by @Cath we need to explicitly include all the levels in the data.

```
Maj <- rep("Major A", times=50)
set.seed(24601) 
Race <- factor(sample(c("Asian","Black", "Am Indian","Hawiian" ,"Hispanic","White","Two or More Races","Not Reported"),
           prob=c(.01,.1,.01,.01,.02,.80,.05,.01),size=50, replace = T), 
           levels=c("Asian","Black", "Am Indian","Hawiian" ,"Hispanic","White","Two or More Races","Not Reported"))
Sex <- factor(sample(c("Female","Male"), prob=c(.98,.02),size=50,replace=T), levels = c("Female","Male"))

Enroll_MajorA <- data.frame(Maj,Sex,Race)
```

Comment: This looks like it runs into the same issue as the answer above. Even though there were no "Asians" in the data set I still need "Asian" to be listed in the table.

Comment: @asokol Updated the answer to include all levels.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not familiar with ```tidyverse```, and I am new to R. I can follow your up to the ```mutate``` line, could you explain what the  ```gather``` and ```unite``` lines are doing?

Comment: @asokol `gather` converts the data from wide to long format and `unite` combines data from two columns into one. I would suggest to run line by line to understand it better.